# How to find out which method is dispatched to an S3 object?

Tags: r, oop, methods

How can I find out which method is being dispatched when I apply a function to an S3 object?

For example, if I run the code

```
df <- data.frame(list("a" = c(1,2,3)), "b" = c(7,8,9))

print(df)
```

I think the method `print.data.frame` is being dispatched because it shows up when running `methods(class="data.frame")`

Is there a way verify this? Such as a function that takes in `print` and `data.frame` and outputs the method used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sloop` package can show you more details. For example

```
sloop::s3_dispatch(print(df))
# => print.data.frame
#  * print.default
```

this shows you all the possible matches, and highlights the one that was actually used (`print.data.frame`)

But in general you need to look at the `class()` of the object you pass to the function. The first class that matches up with the `methods()` listed for the function will be the one called. If you want to see the code of the function that would be used, you could use

```
getS3method("print", "data.frame")
```